# How do I access application folders on a Mac?

Tags: macos, finder

I have a software program where on a PC, I can access sub-folders where the owner's manual, sub-folders, etc. reside.

It is cross-platformed and I installed on my Mac. How do I get to that information and manipulate it on a Mac?

Answer (score 3):

(I'm making a lot of assumptions here) I assume the Mac version of the software comes in a `.dmg` format. Mount the image (double-click on it), and it is likely the manual and everything should be in there.

Otherwise, if the software comes into a `.app`, or installs a `.app` to your `/Applications` folder, then the manual may be inside that `.app`. That `.app` is actually a folder. You can explore it by right-clicking on it and selecting "Show package contents". Then explore in there and see if there is the manual.